# Display a breve over several letters

Tags: math-mode, accents, width

I'm writting with a very dumb question, buy I haven't been able to find anything regarding this topic, nor think of a more general topic to look into.

I'm trying to have a `\breve` which scales according to the argument. As simple as that (however, as difficult for me!).

If someone can provide me a solution or a related topic to look into, I would be very grateful.

Thanks!
Mauro

Comment: Please provide a bit more information as to the intended use. For instance, will `\widebreve` be used in text or math mode (or both)?

Comment: In general this is not a particularly good idea. For the most part you will have size limitations. Plus if used in the text a large one may disturb line spacing. Just think og the problems with `\widehat`. I'd recommend having two syntaxes for whatever breve means in this context. The breve can be used when the argument is small and for larger ones one can use `\somename(...)`. This makes things a lot more readable.

Comment: Yeah, sorry, the question was quite incomplete. The intended use is in both math-mode and text-mode. However, it won't be used often (perhaps 10/20 times in a 200p book). The reason for this is that I'm transcribing a book. If it were my choice, I'd go with hats and widehats. It may seem stupid, but I have some reasons to follow the hand-written version. So, the idea would it be to create some \widebreve command which will draw an scaled breve, that won't look too ugly (won't be nice either). It should scale for 2 capital letters (I ain't using a word either :P ). Thanks =)

Answer (score 6):

Hmm not sure I like the result but...

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

% merge \overbrace and \underbrace
\makeatletter
\def\widebreve#1{\mathop{\vbox{\m@th\ialign{##\crcr\noalign{\kern3\p@}%
      \brevefill\crcr\noalign{\kern3\p@\nointerlineskip}%
      $\hfil\displaystyle{#1}\hfil$\crcr}}}\limits}

\def\brevefill{$\m@th \setbox\z@\hbox{$\braceld$}%
  \bracelu\leaders\vrule \@height\ht\z@ \@depth\z@\hfill\braceru$}
\makeatletter

\begin{document}

$\breve{a} \breve{AB}  \breve{abc}$


$\widebreve{a}\widebreve{AB}\widebreve{abc}$

\end{document}
```

or

```
\def\brevefill{$\scriptscriptstyle\m@th \setbox\z@\hbox{$\scriptscriptstyle\braceld$}%
  \bracelu\leaders\vrule \@height\ht\z@ \@depth\z@\hfill\braceru$}
```

for less heavy version.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. You certainly did an interesting job. However, as you say, the result ain't very good. Of course I knew when I asked that it was something difficult to achieve. However while looking at the whole document, the widebreve it's way too thick.  My question is probably stupid, because my guess is that what the code is doing is scaling the breve character right? But isn't there a way to make it scale withouth changing the thickness? I guess it isn't. Another solution might be, instead of a full widebreve, a breve which is half the horizontal space of the argument and centered?

Comment: @Sabian it's not using the breve character it is using the parts of `\underbrace` (the rotated `{` ) but without th emiddle bit. The scriptscript code not shown in the image is better (but still not great)

Comment: Yes, I changed the brevefill with the less heavy one and it's certainly better but still to thick. In any case, thanks a lot for the effort you put into this. Really.

Comment: @Sabian I summoned the tikz mafia, see what happens.... http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/16599968#16599968

Comment: Hi David, sorry to bother again. I waited for this topic to interest someone else for about a month with no luck, so I tried to blindly edit your macro in order a) to understand it (MISSION FAILED), b) to see for alternatives that help me in my case. I managed to thikn a less general, but maybe aesthetically better solution for my problem. I tryed using a rotated parethesis as the breve faker. I deleted the bracelu and replaced braceru for the rotated parenthesis, in your less heavy brevefill version. The problem is it's not centrated. How can I achive that?
BTW: How to send MPs in this site?

Answer (score 2):

Finally with a lot of fine tuning, and clearly abusing of LaTeX capabilities, I managed a result I'm almost happy with. It only works for the specified variables I was using, but I'm posting it here because someone with somewhat the same problem might find it useful.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\makeatletter
\def\widebreve#1{\mathop{\vbox{\m@th\ialign{##\crcr\noalign{\kern\p@}%
  \brevefill\crcr\noalign{\kern0.1\p@\nointerlineskip}%
  $\hfil\displaystyle{#1}\hfil$\crcr}}}\limits}


\def\brevefill{$\m@th \setbox\z@\hbox{}%
 \hfill\scalebox{0.7}{\rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{(}} \kern4pt $}
\makeatletter


\begin{document}

\[
\widebreve{ON} \breve O
\]

\end{document}
```

[image: Example]

For finetuning look for:

-"\mkern0.1\p@" deals with the height of the breve.

-"scalebox{0.7}" gives the size of the breve.

-"\kern4pt" is used for adjusting the horizontal position of the breve.

Comment: I would recommend using a dual syntax instead. Using the breve for shorter arguments and say `Name(...)` for more complicated ones. One get into the same kind of trouble with `\widehat`

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you mean.

Comment: Say you have the fourier transform. Some people write this as `\hat{f}`. But `\widehat` can only stretch so far, so for a complicated expression I'd recommend using something similar to `\operatorname{Fourier}(long conplicated)`, thus you have one syntax for simple expressions and a name based one for longer expressions

Comment: I agree, but in this case it wasn't an operator but a let's say, class.

Comment: Same argument. These growing accents have their limits. We see questions like yours from time to time so it is a real life problem. My solution is just to look at it from another angle

Comment: Terrific! Just what I needed :D