# How to define a \widebreve command?

Tags: math-mode, accents

I would like to define a `\widebreve` command to employ with large symbols (such as `$M$`, or letter combinations such as `$AB$`) in math mode.

Does someone know how to do it?

Comment: Maybe http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/190996/display-a-breve-over-several-letters

Comment: there isn't anything like this shown in the comprehensive symbols list (`texdoc comprehensive`), but it might be constructed by using the `\wideparen` from `mathabx` and rotating it to turn it upside down.  (see http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/44277/579 regarding a warning about using accents from `mathabx`.)