# Fractions common denominator

Tags: fractions

I am trying to receive this look of fractions [image]

I need the **red** numbers, which are over the fractions. 
*They need to be normal, not handwritten-like.
Here is my code

```
\documentclass[10pt,oneside,a5paper]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
    $\dfrac{13}{25}, \dfrac{9}{20}, \dfrac{3}{4},
    \dfrac{3}{4}, \dfrac{3}{5}, \dfrac{1}{6};$
\end{document}
```

Comment: Do they also have to be printed in such a handwritten-like font?

Comment: They need to be normal, not handwritten-like.

Comment: Do you need the curved lines below the numbers?

Comment: It would be nice.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Why take the risk of an error in computing ?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{xintgcd}

\newsavebox\mybox
\newcommand{\fractionswithlcm}[1]{%
  \sbox\mybox{\gdef\simeondenominators{}%
      \def\fracm##1##2{\xdef\simeondenominators{\simeondenominators{##2}}}%
      $#1$}%
  \edef\simeonlcm{\xintLCMof{\simeondenominators}}%
  {\underbrace{#1}_{\displaystyle\simeonlcm}}%
}
\newcommand{\fracm}[2]{%
  \overset{\xintiiQuo{\simeonlcm}{#2}}%
          {\overset{\displaystyle\smile}{\frac{#1}{#2}}}%
}

\begin{document}

\[
\fractionswithlcm{
  \fracm{13}{25},
  \fracm{9}{20},
  \fracm{3}{4},
  \fracm{3}{5},
  \fracm{1}{6}
}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

---

As per OP request in a comment, here is with only the numbers on top but not anymore the big underbrace.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{xintgcd}

\newsavebox\mybox
\newcommand{\fractionswithlcm}[1]{%
  \sbox\mybox{\gdef\simeondenominators{}%
      \def\fracm##1##2{\xdef\simeondenominators{\simeondenominators{##2}}}%
      $#1$}%
  \edef\simeonlcm{\xintLCMof{\simeondenominators}}%
  #1%
}
\newcommand{\fracm}[2]{%
  \overset{\xintiiQuo{\simeonlcm}{#2}}%
          {\overset{\displaystyle\smile}{\frac{#1}{#2}}}%
}

\begin{document}

\[
\fractionswithlcm{
  \fracm{13}{25},
  \fracm{9}{20},
  \fracm{3}{4},
  \fracm{3}{5},
  \fracm{1}{6}
}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I was kind of expecting it. :-)

Comment: Conversely, why take the risk of an error in code? ;-)

Comment: @R.. there is indeed a risk here as I should probably not have the `\fracm` globally defined to use the `\xintiiQuo{\simeonlcm}{#2}` operation. In this approach the `\fracm` should arguably be a macro whose usage is strictly restricted to inside `\fractionswithlcm` argument...

Comment: @egreg your answer without `expl3`/`xparse` demonstrates indeed that one can vanquish addictions :) ... I am not as strong !

Comment: Amazing. Can you remove the big bracket with number 300. I need only the fractions with the curves.

Comment: @SimeonSimeonov done...

Comment: Only one last thing for special cases where i need to use  [llink] (https://pastebin.com/bpDKRK1y) 
Can you make this code with curved smile? So I enter for example myfrac{12}{13}{25} manually but it appears with curved smile above.
I tried but I have problems with rows.

Comment: @SimeonSimeonov you probably want `\newcommand{\myfrac}[3]{\overset{#1}{\overset{\displaystyle\smile}{\dfrac{#2}{#3}}}}`

Comment: @SimeonSimeonov then the `\fracm` should be `\newcommand{\fracm}[2]{\myfrac{\xintiiQuo{\simeonlcm}{#2}}{#1}{#2}}`

Comment: for the record: my answer regarding the actual typesetting was copied over from @egreg's one. I only added the automatic computation of the l.c.m and related quotient.

Answer (score 12):

For the curved symbol you can use `\smile`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\newcommand{\fractionswithlcm}[2]{%
  {\underbrace{#1}_{\displaystyle#2}}%
}
\newcommand{\fracm}[3]{%
  \overset{#1}{\overset{\displaystyle\smile}{\frac{#2}{#3}}}%
}

\begin{document}

\[
\fractionswithlcm{
  \fracm{12}{13}{25},
  \fracm{15}{9}{20},
  \fracm{75}{3}{4},
  \fracm{60}{3}{5},
  \fracm{50}{1}{6}
}{300}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

With `\widehat` instead of curves:

[image: mew]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
$\overset{\underbrace{
\underset{\widehat{\dfrac{13}{25},}}{12}
\underset{\widehat{\dfrac{9}{20}},}{15}
\underset{\widehat{\dfrac{3}{4}},\ }{75}
\underset{\widehat{\dfrac{1}{6}},\ }{60}
\underset{\widehat{\dfrac{3}{5}}\ }{50}
}}{300}$
\end{document}
```

Edit: Ok, with curves

[image: mwe]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
% https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/191042/11604
\makeatletter
\def\widebreve#1{\mathop{\vbox{\m@th\ialign{##\crcr\noalign{\kern3\p@}%
      \brevefill\crcr\noalign{\kern3\p@\nointerlineskip}%
      $\hfil\displaystyle{#1}\hfil$\crcr}}}\limits}

\def\brevefill{$\m@th \setbox\z@\hbox{$\braceld$}%
  \bracelu\leaders\vrule \@height\ht\z@ \@depth\z@\hfill\braceru$}
\makeatletter

\begin{document}
$\overset{\underbrace{
\underset{\widebreve{\dfrac{13}{\makebox[1em]{25}}},}{12}
\underset{\widebreve{\dfrac{9}{\makebox[1em]{20}}},}{15}
\underset{\widebreve{\dfrac{3}{\makebox[1em]{4}}},}{75}
\underset{\widebreve{\dfrac{1}{\makebox[1em]{6}}},}{60}
\underset{\widebreve{\dfrac{3}{\makebox[1em]{5}}}}{50}
}}{300}$
\end{document}
```

Comment: But I think that the mark should be below the top numbers, not above the 2nd row numbers.

Comment: It should be curved up, like half circle.

Comment: I think they should be under and centered with the 1st row numbers. Lets see.

Comment: BTW not relevant to the TeX part, but in this answer 3/5 and 1/6 are switched relative to the question (while the numbers above are not).

Answer (score 3):

What about this?

```
\documentclass[10pt,oneside,a5paper]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\newcommand{\myfrac}[3]{\overset{#1}{\dfrac{#2}{#3}}}

\begin{document}
$\myfrac{12}{13}{25}, \myfrac{15}{9}{20}, \myfrac{75}{3}{4}, \myfrac{60}{3}{5}, \myfrac{50}{1}{6}$
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I like it. But I need the curved lines above. I don't know if it's possible.Thank you!